# Stripe Simple Checkout Custom Data Field

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe's simple checkout system.

I want to include a custom field so that I can match an `item_id` to an order in my database.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple

They don't seem to mention it in their documentation but it seems pretty essential for online services. **How do I attach a custom id field that will be recorded with the order?**

```
echo '<form action="/charge" method="POST">';
echo '<script ';
  echo 'src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" ';
  echo 'data-key="pk_test_ksdjhg8dsgsghdsgh" ';
  echo 'data-email="email@example.com" ';
  echo 'data-name="example.com" ';
  //echo 'data-bitcoin="true" ';
  echo 'data-description="Campaign" ';
  echo 'data-currency="usd" ';
  echo 'data-amount="2000" ';
  echo 'data-locale="auto">';
echo '</script>';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: what about the token?
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: @Mauro can I use that for the simple integration though?

Comment: As the documentation says: Only available with the custom integration

Comment: Well I think I can include it in the data-description "Campaign #3523"....

Comment: it's pretty ugly ... BTW printing html with echo in php is pretty ugly too

Comment: Well, it provides feedback to the buyer that they are buying a campaign with a traceable ID number. Ugly but also reassuring...

Comment: How would you print HTML for a dynamic php website?

Comment: there are few many ways to prevent use echo. pure html and use php tags in the middle for example... templating engines (like twig, smarty)

Comment: I am used to echo though. I like it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318033/outputting-html-with-echo-considered-bad-practice-in-php

Comment: I dunno but I just find <?php ?> everywhere really really hard to read....and escaping is no problem for me.

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org

Comment: ty i'll look into it :) :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you require to send your custom data-field with stripe checkout and trying to match with your data base. If I'm right? Follow below detail.

For include custom data you need to use hidden input like below:

```
echo '<form action="/charge" method="POST">';
echo '<script ';
  echo 'src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" ';
  echo 'data-key="pk_test_ksdjhg8dsgsghdsgh" ';
  echo 'data-email="email@example.com" ';
  echo 'data-name="example.com" ';
  //echo 'data-bitcoin="true" ';
  echo 'data-description="Campaign" ';
  echo 'data-currency="usd" ';
  echo 'data-amount="2000" ';
  echo 'data-locale="auto">';
echo '</script>';
echo '<input name="item_id" value="SOMEVALUEHERE" type="hidden">';
echo '</form>';
```

In above code, I include  hidden for *item_id*. You can get the value from that input field in your PHP page like:

```
$item_id = $_POST["item_id"];
```

Comment: Oh it will post that to the return address?

Comment: Not working for me - the Stripe JS is stripping any extra form inputs.

Comment: Dear @Alex, Do not completely rely on this answer because this is based on OP's question so it's may require some change as per your request.

Comment: Right you are - though, there is not much to it - add a hidden input, let the checkout.js run and make its POST request. I can tell you this much - when I do it, it strips the extra field from the form before making the request. I am now using different endpoint urls, and later I guess jump into stripe.js.

Answer (score 0):

My experience, which is that custom fields are not possible using the basic Stripe checkout, concurs with the accepted answer on this very similar question:

[How to add custom fields to popup form of Stripe Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592382/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-popup-form-of-stripe-checkout)

I believe the best route forward would be to get handy with stripe.js and create a custom payment form:

https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form

I am working around that at present by using different endpoint URLs in the form actions to do different things. This works fine, but I may end up using stripe.js in the production code.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this to add extra information

```
echo '<form action="/charge?item_id=123" method="POST">';
```

and use `$_REQUEST['item_id']` in stead of `$_POST['item_id']` in the charge page to get the value.

Not my preferred way of working, but in this case it solves the problem.